# Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "F:\\Angular Projects\\cmp-databinding-start"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "F:\Angular Projects\cmp-databinding-start".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\shubh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)

Comment: You should provide more information on your question. What are you trying to do? When are you getting this error? Also, what is your question?

Comment: I downloaded a simple angular project (1 component only) . Now i tried to run this on my node.js command prompt using ng serve command and next moment i got this error Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "F:\\Angular Projects\\cmp-databinding-start".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\shubh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)

Answer (score 0):

You can try delete currently nodemodule after that intall with : npm install